# PHP Function Scope Failure

Tags: php, api, class, function, scope

I am struggling to understand scope and what's preventing my new code from working (assuming it is a scope issue).

The following function is in a file `PATH.'/includes/custom-functions.php'` that references a class:

```
    function infusion() {
      require_once(PATH.'/classes/infusion.php'); //PATH is defined in WordPress from ~/wp-content/themes/theme/
      return new infusion();
    }
```

The class is reliant on `PATH.'/api/isdk.php'` and connection credentials from another file within `/api/` directory. From within `PATH .'/includes/custom-functions.php'`, I have many other functions that call `$infusion = infusion();` and work perfectly.

**PROBLEM**
I have created a new file: `PATH.'/includes/report.php'` which I need to access `$infusion = infusion();`but can't get to work by either repeating the `function infusion()` definition from above; using `require_once();`; or using `include();`. All 3 of those options simply kill the rest of the code and I can only come to the conclusion - well, I have no conclusion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the code isn't using namespaces, therefore you aren't permitted to redeclare the `infusion` function (either by redefining the function, or re-including the class).

Your `includes/report.php` file should simply have:

```
require_once PATH.'/includes/custom-functions.php';

// your other code here ...

$infusion = infusion();
```

It may be the case that other files / classes that you're including in your file are already requiring `custom-functions.php` along the line, so you may be able to skip that entirely.  Also note that the `PATH` constant should have already been defined somewhere (either directly or via an `include`d file) before you attempt to use it.  If you set your `error_reporting` to include `E_ALL`, you'll get a notification in your error log if that constant doesn't exist.

If that fails, your error log(s) may provide some additional background on what your issue is.

Comment: I'll have to poke around some more...

Double-checked that none of the files in question were already requiring `custom-functions.php`, the `PATH` constant has been declared prior to referencing it, but when I add `require_once();`, it break output, so I try adding error reporting.

Comment: I'm back with the same issue and it's got me completely bum-fuzzled!

I have a file handler.php that opens like this: